# Five star rating component: How to get rid of all JavaScript code and replace it with only CSS?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I built a five star simple component (to be used for ranking). The component works fine. I used JavaScript to save the result (when user click on a star (which is not shown here) ).

The problem I have is that I didn't found a **proper way** to simulate the `mouseover` event (when you pass the mouse over a star and before clicking). So I did it using JavaScript.

Is there a **proper way** to use only CSS to achieve this (instead of all those JS lines)?

I'm sharing what I already did.

```js
document.getElementById('star1').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 this.classList.add("fa-star");
});
document.getElementById('star1').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star");
 this.classList.add("fa-star-o");
});

document.getElementById('star2').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 this.classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star");
});
document.getElementById('star2').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star");
 this.classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star-o");
});

document.getElementById('star3').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 this.classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star");
});
document.getElementById('star3').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star");
 this.classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star-o");
});

document.getElementById('star4').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 this.classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.add("fa-star");
});
document.getElementById('star4').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star");
 this.classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.add("fa-star-o");
});

document.getElementById('star5').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 this.classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.add("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star4').classList.remove("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star4').classList.add("fa-star");
});
document.getElementById('star5').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 this.classList.remove("fa-star");
 this.classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star1').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star2').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star3').classList.add("fa-star-o");
 document.getElementById('star4').classList.remove("fa-star");
 document.getElementById('star4').classList.add("fa-star-o");
});
```

```css
.content > span > i{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #f0d124;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#star1:hover #star1{
 /*an example: I don't know what to do here???*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content">
 <span><i id="star1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
 <span><i id="star2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
 <span><i id="star3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
 <span><i id="star4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
 <span><i id="star5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This demo uses radio buttons for the "sticking" feature. A click will keep selected star(s) highlighted, but it will only persist until the page is reloaded of course. **Note:** if there is a partial selection of stars we can hover over the remaining unselected stars and the hover effect still works properly.

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      color: #FFB300;
      background: #000;
      font: 700 16px/1.5 Verdana;
    }
    
    .rating {
      font-size: 0;
    }
    
    .set {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #FC0;
    }
    
    .set:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .star {
      float: right;
      padding-left: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #FFB300;
    }
    
    .star:last-child {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    .rad {
      display: none;
    }
    /* 1. hover over a label.star directly and display
    ||    the full gold star in the ::before pseudo
    ||    element.
    */
    /* 2. hover over a label.star and display it and all
    ||    other label.star before it as a full gold star
    */
    /* 3. check a label.star and display it and all other
    ||    label.star before it as a full gold star.
    ||    Full persistent empty stars are possible because
    ||    of the :checked pseudo-selector
    */
    .star:hover:before,
    .star:hover~.star:before,
    .rad:checked~.star:before {
      content: "\f005";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="rating">
    <fieldset class='set'>
      <legend>Rate It</legend>
      <input id="rad5" class="rad" name="rad" type="radio">
      <label for="rad5" class="star fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></label>
      <input id="rad4" class="rad" name="rad" type="radio">
      <label for="rad4" class="star fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></label>
      <input id="rad3" class="rad" name="rad" type="radio">
      <label for="rad3" class="star fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></label>
      <input id="rad2" class="rad" name="rad" type="radio">
      <label for="rad2" class="star fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></label>
      <input id="rad1" class="rad" name="rad" type="radio">
      <label for="rad1" class="star fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></label>
    </fieldset>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way of doing it with FontAwesome that your are using:

```css
body {
  font-size: 44px;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

span:hover i:before,
span:hover~span i:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content">
  <span><i id="star1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
  <span><i id="star2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
  <span><i id="star3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
  <span><i id="star4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
  <span><i id="star5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
</div>
```

It has some "limitations" that need to be considered. It needs [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to reverse the elements render order so that "~"-selector works as intended. So keep that in mind when generating the javascript when you save the results.

[Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) is pretty well supported nowdays.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the full job. Looks "dirty" but works.

```css
.content > span > i,.content > span > span{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #f0d124;
 cursor: pointer;
}

span > i:before{
  content:"\f006"
}

.content > span{
  position: relative;
  width: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span > span{
  position: absolute;
}

span > i{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1
}

.back{
  z-index:0;
}

.left_1{
  left:-60px;
}

.left_2{
  left:calc(-60px*2);
}

.left_3{
  left:calc(-60px*3);
}

.left_4{
  left:calc(-60px*4);
}

span:hover > i:before, span:hover > span:before {
   content:"\f005"
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content"> 
    <span><i id="star1" class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
    <span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_1"></span>
      <i id="star2" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    </span>
    <span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_2"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_1"></span>
      <i id="star3" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    </span>
    <span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_3"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_2"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_1"></span>
      <i id="star4" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    </span>
    <span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_4"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_3"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_2"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star-o back left_1"></span>
      <i id="star5" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    </span>  
</div>
```